# C# Refresh File to get the correct lastwritetime for file which is being written by another application

Tags: c#, refresh

first thanks for the help.

I am writing a C# application which to copy some files based on their modification date.
The program works for most of the time, except when handling file which is being written by another application. For these files, i realised that the file last modification date will not update until i refresh it manually.

I had the below code to work around, which all the file get refesh first, ensure the modification date is update before i store in the list

```
DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Testing");

var listofallfile = directory.GetFiles();
var listOfFilesInSpecifiedPeriod = new List<FileInfo>();
            
foreach (var file in listofallfile)
{
    file.Refresh();
    if (file.LastWriteTime>= fromDate && file.LastWriteTime <= toDate)
     {
       listOfFilesInSpecifiedPeriod.Add(file);
     }
}
```

But i would like to have a more simple lines express that. Is there a way to refrest the file modifcation date in the code below?

```
DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Testing");

var listOfFilesInSpecifiedPeriod = directory.GetFiles()
                            .Where(file => file.LastWriteTime >= fromDate && file.LastWriteTime <= toDate);
```

Thanks

Comment: Not the answer to your question, but you should use `EnumerateFiles` instead of `GetFiles`

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Yes, i understand now EnumerateFiles is more efficient when working with large amount of file. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [forEach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.foreach?view=net-5.0) function of the list. It's not on `IEnumerable` but it does the trick:

```
var listOfFilesInSpecifiedPeriod = directory.GetFiles().ToList();
listOfFilesInSpecifiedPeriod.forEach(file => file.Refresh());
listOfFilesInSpecifiedPeriod = listOfFilesInSpecifiedPeriod.Where(file => file.LastWriteTime >= fromDate && file.LastWriteTime <= toDate).ToList();
```